# mactex (no-gui) download failure

Tags: shell, latex, homebrew

I want to ask a question about downloading the MacTex distribution as part of the Manim installation [setup](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/macos.html#optional-dependencies) whilst learning beginner-level Linux command line scripting.

Currently, I'm using macOS Catalina and I tried to download MacTex through the following command:

```
brew install --cask mactex-no-gui
```

via homebrew.

However, I keep getting this response in return:

```
==> Downloading http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-20210328.pkg
==> Downloading from https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-20210328.pkg

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Download failed on Cask 'mactex-no-gui' with message: 
Download failed: http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-20210328.pkg
```

I'm not sure why this is happening... I tried:

```
ping http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-20210328.pkg
```

which returns

```
ping: cannot resolve http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-20210328.pkg: Unknown host
```

However, the root domain `mirror.ctan.org` is still up and working.

I couldn't find the package named in the command response on the mirror repository although I'm not sure why it doesn't download the latest build.

What is the root issue behind this matter?